# Handle flask API in react-redux using axios

Tags: reactjs, redux, promise, react-redux, axios

Good evening everyone!

I'm a beginner in React-Redux. I'm trying to make a classification app using Flask API and ReactJS as its front-end. When I trying to call API in Redux (on action file) and then display prediction result from the input, the result is always "500 server error", I don't know whether it is right or not (I have checked this API in Postman its okay).

My goal from this apps is to adding information from the data inside the payload object and display prediction result inside component through inputted text. I have been trying to get this work for the past day and I'm really confused. I'm using axios and promise to handle the call

Any help will be greatly appreciated. I'm sorry if this sounds likely stupid or wrong
By the way, there is output from the console

[Output console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RXTZ.png)

**This is action in contentAction.js:**

```
export const setPredict = content => ({
   type: PREDICT_CLASS,
   content 
})
export const savePredict = content => (

    (dispatch ) => {
        console.log("Predict...")
    dispatch({type: PREDICT_CLASS})
    const payload = content

    const contents = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        api.post('/predicts', payload).then((response) => {
            dispatch(setPredict(response.data.data))
            resolve({status: true})
        }).catch((e)=> {
            reject(e)
        })
    })

    return contents

 }
)
```

**This is action in contentReducer.js:**

```
import * as actions from '../actions/actionTypes'

const initState = {
    content: {},
    loading: false,
}

const contentReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actions.PREDICT_CLASS:
            return {content: action.payload, loading: false}
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
export default contentReducer
```

**container.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import {withState, withHandlers, compose, lifecycle} from 'recompose'
import classifierComponent from '../pages/contentPages'
import {savePredict} from '../../actions/contentActions'
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux'

// state 
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    content: state.content,
    predicts: state.predicts,
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
   savePredict: bindActionCreators(savePredict, dispatch),
})

export default compose(
    connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),
    withState('contentValue', 'setContentValue', ''),
    withState('predicts', 'setPredicts', ''),
    withState('loading', 'setLoading', false),
    withHandlers({
        handleContent: props => (event) => {
            event.preventDefault()
            props.setContentValue(event.target.value)
        },
        onSubmit: props => (event) => {
            event.preventDefault()
            props.setLoading(true)
            props.setContentValue(event.target.value)
            props.setPredicts(event.target.value)
            props.savePredict(props)
        }
    }),
)(classifierComponent)
```

**component.js**

```
const contentPages = ({handleContent, contentValue, predicts, onSubmit, loading}) => {
    return (
        <>
            <Container>
                <h1>Let's Classified Content!</h1>
                <Form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                    <TextArea 
                        placeholder='Tell us more' 
                        onChange={handleContent}
                        value={contentValue}
                        name="content"
                    />
                    <Button 
                        style={{marginTop: "20px"}} 
                        primary
                        type="submit"
                        disabled={loading}
                    >
                        {loading? 'Making Prediction' : 'Predict'}
                    </Button>
                </Form>
                <br/>
                <p>Predicted: {predicts}</p>
            </Container>
        </>
    );
};

contentPages.propTypes = {
    handleContent: PropTypes.func,
    contentClick: PropTypes.func,
    contentValue: PropTypes.string,
    predicts: PropTypes.string,
    loading: PropTypes.bool,
};

export default contentPages;
```

**This is an interface that I'm expected**
[Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnMyE.png)

Ps. it should be display an output

**webUrl api**

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default axios.create({
    baseURL: `http://127.0.0.1:5000/api`,
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    },
    timeout: 10000,
});
```

**this is index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux'
import rootReducer from './reducers/contentReducer'
import {BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom'
import Routes from './routes/routes'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk))
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
      <Routes/>
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there's an unresolved promise.

In the contentAction use a try/catch like so

```js
export const setPredict = content => ({
   type: PREDICT_CLASS,
   content 
})
export const savePredict = content => (

    (dispatch ) => {
        console.log("Predict...")
    dispatch({type: PREDICT_CLASS})
    const payload = content

    const contents = async () => {

      try{
const response = await  api.post('/predicts', payload)
       dispatch(setPredict(response.data.data))
}
catch(error) {
Throw error

}
    })
}

    return contents

 }
)
```

Excuse my indentation

Comment: Thanks, it's works! But I'm still confused how can I return the prediction value (predict attribute) from its container (both onsubmit and handle text) based on json API like {data:"Setiap tahun, siswa lebih dari 10.000 sekolah di 160 negara mengikuti ujian Cambridge...", "predict":"positive"}?